# jsp and html5 localStorage size

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, local-storage

I have encountered an issue on which I could not find any solution.
I need information about localStorage size which is calculated looking at keys stored, in my javascript function, however I need that information inside my jsp page, is there any way I could do this?

Comment: you can **send** it to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LocalStorage is a client/browser thing. You can't access it by java, because when jsp is running, is on the server. You'll have to send the information to the server, there is no other way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, gonna send that info to server.